# Different output of base64_encode function with same input?

Tags: php, encryption

While using  `base64_encode` function I am getting different outputs with the same input. Here is my code :

```
$authentication_key="NKu84HvQaPRr";
$iv="abcdef987654";
$input_str="";
$encrypt=openssl_encrypt($input_str, 'AES-128-CBC', $authentication_key, 1,     $iv);
$request_str = base64_encode($encrypt);

$request_str1 = base64_encode("�P��@��-�k� ��");
```

`openssl_encrypt` yields output: `�P��@��-�k� ��`

`$request_str`  outputs: `CrxQwOxA4QzzLYdroiD8mw==`

`$request_str1` outputs `77+9UO+/ve+/vUDvv70M77+9Le+/vWvvv70g77+977+9`

I need help in understanding this difference in output of `base64_encode` with the same input.

Thanks.

Comment: Those `�` represent characters that cannot be rendered. However, those characters are _not_ `�`. So the two input strings are not the same.

Comment: Have you tried to decrypt both again? My guess is that `$request_str1` won't work as expected, for the reasons @KIKOSoftware mentioned.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Is it the same behaviour when variable is passed in base64_encode

Comment: What does that mean? When *what* variable is passed?

Answer (score 2):

Different output is caused by different input.

Do the reverse operation and compare:

```
$a = base64_decode('CrxQwOxA4QzzLYdroiD8mw==');
$b = base64_decode('77+9UO+/ve+/vUDvv70M77+9Le+/vWvvv70g77+977+9');
```

Encrypted strings are binary data and you cannot reliably visualise raw binary data. But you can dump to hexadecimal:

```
var_dump($a, $b, bin2hex($a), bin2hex($b));
```

```
string(16) "
�P��@��-�k� ��"
string(33) "�P��@��-�k� ��"
string(32) "0abc50c0ec40e10cf32d876ba220fc9b"
string(66) "efbfbd50efbfbdefbfbd40efbfbd0cefbfbd2defbfbd6befbfbd20efbfbdefbfbd"
```

Comment: Nice prove of the difference of the inputs.